# How did the author change the inequality into an equality?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

While trying to prove that the function $f(n)=8x+128$ is $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$, the author turns an inequality into an equality.

This is what he did:

> We wish to show that $f(x) = \mathcal{O}(n^2)$. According to the definition, in
>   order to show this we need to find an integer $n_0$ and a constant $c>0$
>   such that for all integers $n \geq n_0$, $f(x) \leq cn^2$.
>                 It does not matter what the particular constants are -- as long as they exist! E.g., suppose we choose $c=1$. Then
>
> \begin{align*}
> f(n) \leq cn^2 &\rightarrow 8n + 128 \leq n^2\\
> &\rightarrow 8n \leq n^2 - 128\\
> &\rightarrow 0 \leq n^2 - 8n - 128\\
> &\rightarrow 0 \leq (n - 16)(n + 8)
> \end{align*}
>
> **Since $(n+8)>0$ for all values of $n \geq 0$, we conclude that $(n_0 - 16) \geq 0$ I.e $n_0=16$**

How does he determine that $n_0$ is $16$? At the very least I would assume that $n_0 \geq 16$.

Comment: What the author is saying is that as _long_ as $n\geq 16$ then $8n+128\leq n^2$; since all we need is any particular value of $n_0$ that satisfies this, we can simply take $n_0=16$.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki That makes sense. So if $n \geq 16$ that means $n_0 \leq 16$, and we can choose any $n_0 \leq 16$?

Comment: No - you need to choose an $n_0$ such that _all_ $n\geq n_0$ satisfy the inequality.  So imagine choosing $n_0=10$; then $n=12$ satisfies $n\geq n_0$ but not the (target) inequality $8n+128\leq n^2$ (since $8\cdot 12+128 = 224\not\leq 144=12^2$).  You can choose any $n_0$ that's at least 16 and have $n\geq n_0\implies 8n+128\leq n^2$; 16 is then just the most convenient value.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Thanks for clarifying it. If you post an answer I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author has shown that as long as $n\geq 16$ then $8n+128\leq n^2$; since all we need to say that $8n+128\in O(n^2)$ is to find *any* particular value of $n_0$ that satisfies $(n\geq n_0)\implies (8n+128\leq n^2)$, it's clear that $n_0=16$ will do the trick.  But note that values of $n_0$ less than $16$ won't necessarily; for instance, if we tried to take $n_0=10$, then a counterexample to the statement $(n\geq n_0)\implies (8n+128\leq n^2$) would be $n=12$, since then $n\geq n_0$, but $8n+128 = 8\cdot 12+128 = 224\not\leq144 = n^2$.

Comment: Why did he substitute $n$ for $n_0$ in $(n-16)$?